# Can someone explain why I have this error column does not exist?

Tags: postgresql

Insert into Customer(
Customerid,
Username,
Fname,
Lname,
Street1,
Street2,
City,
State,
Zip

) VALUES(42, “Guitarhero”, “Wes”, “Montgomery”, “Mainstreet”, “Manhattan”, “NY”, 12304);
ERROR:  column "“guitarhero”" does not exist

Comment: Changing to single quotes does not help.

Answer (score 0):

You're using double quotes for strings instead of single quotes. Double quotes indicate a column name, and single quotes indicate a string. Try this:

```sql
Insert into Customer (Customerid, Username, Fname, Lname, Street1, Street2, City, State, Zip)
VALUES (42, 'Guitarhero', 'Wes', 'Montgomery', 'Mainstreet', 'Manhattan', 'NY', 12304);
```

Also note that you're using uppercase letters in your table and column names, but those will be changed to lowercase by postgres unless you put them in double quotes.

Comment: I trried that and it still did not work insert into customer(
customerid,
username,
fname,
lname,
street1,
street2,
city,
state,
zip) 
VALUES(42, ‘guitarhero’, ‘wes’, ‘montgomery’, ‘mainstreet’, ‘manhattan’, ‘ny’, 12304);

Comment: @brandker What error are you getting now?

Comment: Im getting  column "‘guitarhero’" does not exist  This is my code : insert into customer(
customerid,
username,
fname,
lname,
street1,
street2,
city,
state,
zip)
Values(42, ‘guitarhero’, ‘wes’, ‘montgomery’,’mainstreet’,’broadway’, ‘manhattan’, ‘ny’, 12304);